# Equivalent of defsetf in Scheme

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

Is there an equivalent in Scheme of Common Lisp's `defsetf`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that there isn't an equivalent in standard (RnRS) Scheme, but [SRFI 17](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-17/srfi-17.html), which is supported by some Scheme implementations, allows you to define setters for generalized places.

Comment: Note that srfi-17 uses the runtime value of the accessor, not the form itself.  It's a minor difference but it can be important (usually it means that it's a little slower, and a little more flexible).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. I think `defsetf` allows you to do things in Lisp like `(setf (car x) 5)` i.e. use what appears to be the result of a function as an l-value. But in Scheme, they have to define separate mutating functions, like `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`, to accomplish the same task; the above example would be `(set-car! x 5)`.

Comment: You need these functions in CL too (for example, `rplaca`) -- `setf` is just syntax that expands to them.